# Starting gui after nvidia driver update

Tags: boot, gnome, kali-linux, nvidia, gui

So recently I replaced the *nouveau driver* with the nvidia cuda drivers. It took me a while to get it working but I finally succeeded and I can now perform calculations with my gpu. The only problem now is that I can't use the gui any more. After booting the screen just freezes after starting gnome display manager and **reaching target graphical interface**. I can run commands after using  <kbd>ctrl + alt + f2</kbd> and I know the nvidia drivers are working because I can run `hashcat`. I have set my default display driver to the integrated intel graphics in the bios so it isn't using the nvidia card. Also when I try to launch a graphical program it returns:

```
could not connect to any X display.
```

I'm kind of new to this so it might be something stupid but does anyone know what's going on?

Some additional information: I have an msi laptop with integrated intel graphics and a gtx 860m.

I'm running kali which is installed on a secondary hdd. When I boot I also get some acpi errors but I assume that's unrelated.

Comment: This problem exists since Nvidia first released their drivers and is known as "black screen of death". It is beyond me how they consider it a driver and not malware after so many years, but yes, you install Nvidia or AMD proprietary driver in Linux and they brick your PC. I could use OpenCL on AMD platform w/o having to install proprietary driver, but unfortunately know nothing about Cuda.